# How to turn off or disable vfs file loading in JBOSS AS7

Tags: java, jboss, classloader, vfs

I am using jboss AS7 as server and also i am using the following code for getting all jar files which contains particular resource file.

```
 try {
       urls = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResources("config.properties");
//Here gets all jar files url which contains config.properties file
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new AWGenericException(e);
            }
```

But in the case of JBOSS the all urls are appeared in the form of VFS (virtual file system) format.  So the url strings are looks like follows

```
vfs:/E:/Servers/JBOSS/standalone/deployments/isms.war/WEB-INF/lib/ariba.aribaweb.jar/META-INF/config.properties
```

actually i dont need the vfs url i need the url which appears in regular format which looks like follows.

```
jar:file:/E:/Servers/JBOSS/standalone/deployments/isms.war/WEB-INF/lib/ariba.aribaweb.jar!/META-INF/config.properties
```

Is it possible to turn off this feature (vfs) in JBOSS AS7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it is not possible since JBoss AS7 uses VFS for its storage system.

You can however, go [`getPath()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#getPath%28%29) on your [`URL`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URL.html) Object which will just return your path like:

```
E:/Servers/JBOSS/standalone/deployments/isms.war/WEB-INF/lib/ariba.aribaweb.jar/META-INF/config.properties
```

Which you could in theory add `jar:file:` to the start and replace the `.jar` within the `getPath()` with `.jar!` if you need it to match.